# Rstudio displays "Error in output$plot = renderPlot({ : object 'output' not found" Rshiny Webpage displays no points and an empty plot

Tags: r, plot, shiny, output, shinyapps

I'm making a Rshiny app that overlays two scatterplots on top of each other with the ability to select data to overlay but my Rshiny code is broken due to "object 'output' not found" and a general lack of coding ability.

I'm self-taught and have been trying to fix this problem for the better part of a week, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error's within Rstudio I receive when running line
'output$info = renderPrint({'

- Error in output$info = renderPrint({ : object 'output' not found

and when I run the line 'output$plot = renderPlot({'

- Error in output$plot = renderPlot({ : object 'output' not found

The error's within Rshiny app when running the entire app are:

- Empty plot. No points at all. No ability to select regions from the multiInput dropdown menu
  [Rshiny appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKcup.png)

Here's my library setup just in case

```
library(rsconnect)
library(tidyr)
library(pheatmap)
library(readr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(shiny)
library(dendextend)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
```

```
region1 = as.factor(c("r001[Hypothalamus - Intermediate Zone]","r001[Hypothalamus - Intermediate Zone]", "r001[Hypothalamus - Intermediate Zone]","r003[Optic tectum - neuropil]","r003[Optic tectum - neuropil]",  "r003[Optic tectum - neuropil]"))
region2 = as.factor(c("r001[Hypothalamus - Intermediate Zone]", "r003[Optic tectum - neuropil]", "r004[Rhombomere 5 - Ventromedial]",  "r001[Hypothalamus - Intermediate Zone]", "r003[Optic tectum - neuropil]", " r004[Rhombomere 5 - Ventromedial]"))
corvalue = as.numeric(c("1.000000000", "0.347262124", "-0.217184495", "0.347262124", "1.000000000", "-0.279342601"))
distvalue = as.numeric(c("0.0", "42.6","88.7", " 42.6", "0.0", "82.9"))
complete_vectp = data.frame(region1, region2, corvalue, distvalue)

p_names = levels(as.factor(complete_vectp$region2))

# - Forloop that is supposed to generate the separate plots

for (i in 1:length(p_names)) {
  
  strpattern <- substr(p_names[i], 1, 4) 
  regionx = complete_vectp %>% #Section off by region name
    filter(grepl(strpattern, region2))
  
  #gives all the regions without the selected region
  comparison_region <- complete_vectp[which(complete_vectp$region1 == p_names[i]), ]
  
  #gives the selected region without the rest of the regions
  other_regions <- complete_vectp[-c(which(complete_vectp$region1 == p_names[i])), ]
  
  subplot = ggplot(other_regions, aes(x = distvalue, y = corvalue))
  
}
as.character(other_regions$region2)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("something"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      multiInput("name", "Select Region",
                 choices = unique(other_regions$region1)
      ),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("info"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)


server = function(input, output) {
  
  other_regions_reactive = reactive({
    other_regions %>%
      dplyr::filter(unique(region1) == input$name)
    
  })
  
  output$info = renderPrint({
    nearPoints(complete_vectp, input$plot_click, input$plot_brush, threshold = 2, maxpoints = 5)
  })
  
  output$plot = renderPlot({  
    ggplot(other_regions_reactive(), aes(x = distvalue, y = corvalue))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code is currently [neither reproducible nor minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We can't run your code because we can't access `complete_vectp`. Can you use a dataset built into R and modify your code so you use the fewest number of lines that still produces the error message? Creating a minimal reproducible example is the best way to get a timely answer.

Comment: Hi @jrcalabrese, thank you for your quick reply! I've added a complete_vectp in the same str() format as my original code. Unfortunately, I cannot chop down the 'ui' or 'server' in the shiny app because I get a different set of errors. Hope this is a bit better to deal with!